# Word order in question with "do you think" and "do you know"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, word-order, questions

People say:

> "**How old** do you think I am?"

and

> "Do you know **how old** I am?"

I am wondering:

1. What's the reason causing the different location of **how old** between the two questions?
2. Can we say

> "Do you think **how old** I am?"

and

> "**How old** do you know I am?"

If we can't, what is the reason?

Comment: Added the question: "How old do you know I am?"

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to note it's not just the location of these two words;  they have completely different structure.  The first question consists of a single clause.  The second has 2 clauses.

Also, the type of answer elicited is different.  For "How old do you think I am?" the answer is a number.  On the other hand, "Do you know how old I am" is a yes/no question.  The statement in (2) would also be a yes/no question, perhaps equivalent of "do you have a guess as to how old I am?"

Comment: Thank you.  Do you mean > On the other hand, "Do you **think** how old I am"?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the particular order you have to follow is that questions are formed according to the type they belong to.

The questions below are wh-questions ([ref.](https://basicenglishspeaking.com/wh-questions/)).

1. with an auxiliary

WH-WORD + AUXILIARY + SUBJECT + MAIN VERB …?

2. without any auxiliary
   (when WH-words replace subjects already)

WH-WORD + MAIN VERB …?

**How old**           do you think I am?
**Where**               do you think they went?
**What road**      do you think they followed?
**When**                do you think it'll rain?
**How**                  do you think we should do?
**Who**                  do you think told them?

The question below are yes-no questions ([ref](https://englishstudypage.com/grammar/yesno-questions/)); they are formed differently.

> Yes / No questions are the questions which are answered yes or no.  It means when we are asking yes/no questions, we are expecting the answer, yes or no.
>
> To form Yes/No questions, we use one of these verbs: auxiliary verbs ( be, do and have ) or modal verbs ( can, may,etc.).
>
> We can not use questions words like what, how, why, who, etc. whilw making Yes/No questions.

**Do**            you know **how old** I am?
**Can**        you tell **where** they went?
**Will**      you know **what road** they followed?
…

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when you form a question in English, you perform three processes:

1. If the main verb is neither an auxiliary verb nor a form of "to be", then replace the main verb with a conjugated form of "do" followed by a bare infinitive.
2. Put the main verb before the subject.
3. Pull the question word to the beginning of the question.

However, process 2 is generally only done in direct questions—questions that you are asking someone as a complete sentence which stands alone. In indirect questions—questions are used as pieces of another sentence—process 2 is not performed.

The question "How old do you think I am?" is a direct question where processes 2 and 3 are applied. So first we have the question word (which is actually two words, "how old"), then the main verb, then the subject.

The question "Do you know how old I am?" is a yes-or-no question which contains an indirect question as a subordinate clause. That indirect question is "how old I am". Since it's an indirect question, process 2 is not applied. And since the entire question "Do you know how old I am?" is a yes-or-no question, it has no question word and process 3 is not applied.

"Do you think how old I am?" sounds like nonsense. The question word is "how old", and it should have been put at the beginning of the question in order for the question to make sense.